# AngularJS convert Zulu date to format date

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a function in AngularJS that gets a date from HTML.
When I print the date to the console, the date is in the format:

**Tue Apr 06 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)**

I need to convert the date to "yyyy-MM-dd" or "dd-MM-yyyy".
When I convert my date to String, the date becomes one day off to yesterday.

```
c.couponByDate = [];

  c.getCouponByDateForm = function() {
    console.log("Zulu Date: " + c.couponFields.endDate);
    //This line of code makes the date one day off: yesterday.
    c.couponFields.endDate = c.couponFields.endDate.toISOString().replace(/T.*$/g,'');
    console.log("Date to String: " + c.couponFields.endDate);
    c.couponByDate = c.getCouponByDateResource.query(c.couponFields, function() {
      if (c.couponByDate.length > 0) {
        c.couponByDate.forEach(function(coupon){
          c.couponFields = coupon;
          c.couponByDateTableDiv = true;
          c.couponByDateExceptionDiv = false;
        })
      } else {
        c.error("No coupons by date: " + c.couponFields.endDate + " were found");
        c.couponByDateExceptionDiv = true;
        c.couponByDateTableDiv = false;
      }
    }, function() {
      c.error("Request could not be completed");
      c.couponByDateExceptionDiv = true;
      c.couponByDateTableDiv = false;
    });
  }

<td>End Date: {{coupon.endDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
```

Comment: On the bottom of page, you can see [Plunker](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) ! help you ?

Comment: I also need to convert the String format of the date to a Date object while keeping the String format. Thanks!